# How can I log visitors IP addresses without utilizing my own server and CGI script?

Tags: javascript, logs, server, ajax

I would like to log visitors IP addresses of my blog, when they make every 1000th page submission: 1000th, 2000th, 3000th, etc.

The counter data is available from JavaScript, as it is a blogger.com blog.

Does any online service exists, where I can register, got a link which is CORS enabled, callable from a javascript AJAX call, and its mere function is to log visitor's data, eg. the IP addresses? Someting similar to https://iplogger.org but where the tracking links are CORS enabled, Allow-Control-Allow-Origin header is set to *

Would be nice, to be able to access uniq user IP counter information too by AJAX call, to show a message for every 500th uniq user.